# "Прыгает-мерцает" footer при загрузке страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, scss

Есть footer, который прижат к низу экрана с помощью `position: fixed;` При открытии страницы, у которой контент больше высоты экрана телефона, мерцает footer. Сначала появляется контент и через ~0,1с появляется footer поверх контента. Следовательно, вопрос: можно ли как-то избавиться от мерцания (прыжка) footer? Предположение: данная проблема возникает из-за большого контента и сначала отрисовывается контент, а после идет подключение footer.

Пробовал использовать `sticky` вместо `fixed`. Пробовал подключать стили с footer в самое начало перед всем кодом - ничего не помогло.

Сайт на 1с битрикс. Подключаю footer следующим образом:

```
<? require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/footer.php"); ?>
```

Структура сайта выглядит следующим образом:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-bottom: rem(130);
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $backgroundWhite;
  margin-top: rem(40);
  padding: rem(20) rem(15);
  border-top: rem(1) solid $backgroundDarkGray;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: это обязательно использовать фиксед?

Comment: @IgorZinchenko , да. Необходимо чтобы footer был прижат к низу viewport. В данном случае footer выполняет роль мобильного меню, следовательно необходимо, чтобы footer был прижат к низу и был в зоне видимости пользователя

Comment: попробуйте critical css вынести повыше всего, проблема должна уйти

Comment: @IgorZinchenko, пробовал не помогло

Comment: В данном случае есть смысл сделать всеже не fixed. Главное сделать минимальную высоту контентной части допустим ```min-height: calc(100vh - %header_height%px - %footer_height%px)```

Comment: или футер так и должен поверх грузиться, проблема больше в том что грузится позже? Тогда можно попробовать поднять футер в дереве ```<div class="wrapper"><footer></footer><main></main></div>```

Comment: @ТёмаKornishon, спасибо большое немного иначе сделал, но именно ваша идея с тем чтобы поднять футер в дереве помогла. Спасибо!